# Ошибка при построении Gradle проекта

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

Я учусь. Использую Intellij Idea и Gradle . Пытаюсь писать под андроид. При построении вылетает вот такая ошибка

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
D:\Projects\MyApplication10\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0-beta1\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
```

В чем проблема?
Gradle скачал и прописал путь к нему в настройках среды

Comment: Ошибки пишите текстом, а не скриншотом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать стабильную версию библиотеки, не бету. Т.е.  23.3.0 вместо 24.0.0-beta1

Comment: Да, действительно. Исправил в `Build.gradle` версии и идея сама подкачала нужные файлы и ошибка устранилась.